# Why is there no article in the phrase 'Je parle français'?

Tags: articles, articles-definis

I know most of the time an article is always needed in French.

There are a couple of exceptions like: profession and nationality.
Je suis canadienne.
Je suis cuisinier.

Why do we drop the article when it comes to speaking languages?

Je parle le français. / Je parle français.
Je ne parle pas le français. Je ne parle pas français.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ***je parle français***, *français* is used adverbially (like say ***[Il voyait rouge](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/voir_rouge)***) so doesn't require an article. Other examples of such usage are:

- ***Je m'habille français.***
- ***Je mange français.***
- ***J'achète français.***
- ***Je roule français.***

*Je parle **le** français* is however possible and correct and so is *je parle **en** français* (which has a slightly different meaning).

This specific usage has expanded to other expressions like:

> ***Il s'habille italien***.
> ***Elle mange bio***.

With *être*, it is no more an adverbial usage so there is agreement with the subject. The lack of article is standard:

- ***Je suis ingénieur.***
- ***Tu es française.***
- ***Ils sont bouddhistes.***

Comment: How is it adverbially? Is it adverbially in English?

Comment: No sure about what you are asking. *Français* is not an adverb but is used here as if it were one. Whether it would be in English or not is irrelevant.