# Can someone explain me better how this grammar rule works?

Tags: grammaire, partitif

I found a video where some one explains in french language you cannot use only the sustantive in a phrase, they say you must include a "detérminant" like an article. (1)so that you must never say_________ and (2)you should say__________, I found these examples:

(1) On ne dit pas **salut filles** > (2) On dit ***salut les filles***
(1) On ne dit pas **Je mange pain** > (2) On dit ***Je mange du pain***

I get I have to combine  "partitifs" with sustantives, and also combine them with a verb, but now I do not know which verbs can be combined with partitifs or the logic in that and which ones cannot, does someone understand this? and if that's the case could you explain this to me?

If I follow the rule I shouldn't say a sustantive without an article or determinant but I've listened people to say Je parle français but they do not say Je parle le français, :( why?

Comment: After which verbs you use the partitive article in front of the noun depends on the meaning of the verb, whether or not the meaning admits speaking about a certain quantity (what the partitive is about),  an answer about [aimer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49558/358) which you can adapt to any verb. About [je parle français](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/30620/358). *Je parle le français* is also said.  There's already a [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/30620/358) and answer about that.

Answer (score 0):

*Je parle **le** français* is possible but rare, unless you specify which French its is about:

> ***Je parle le français de Belgique***.

In ***Je parle français***, the word *français* is kind of an adverb and uses no *déterminant* like say ***[Il voyait rouge](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/voir_rouge)***.

This specific usage has expanded to other expressions like:

> ***Il s'habille italien***.
> ***Elle mange bio***.

Comment: [Why is there no article in the phrase 'Je parle français'?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/30620/358) answered by...

Comment: @None Ah oui, j'avais déjà répondu à cette question. Je vais ajouter mes exemples à l'autre question et fermer celle-ci.